# Text of Derashos HaRan online

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books, internet, rishonim, speeches-addresses

I was looking online for the text of דרשות הר"ן but I have been unsuccessful. Does anyone where I might be able to find it online? (i.e like [this](http://www.ateret4u.com/online/f_01181.html#HtmpReportNum0000_L2))

Comment: Matt's "text link" (while incomplete) looks like that, IMO....what particular property are you referring to when you write "like this"?

Answer (score 5):

daat.ac.il has it [here](http://www.daat.ac.il/daat/vl/tohen.asp?id=362) in pdf format split into two files.

Comment: Minimum character amounts are to encourage you to include more content in your post.

Comment: @DoubleAA Couldn't think of anything to put there, but apparently there was....

Answer (score 5):

[This is a text link, though not all of the drashos are here](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%93%D7%A8%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%94%D7%A8%22%D7%9F)

[and this is a link to a pdf](http://hebrewbooks.org/41560)

Answer (score 2):

Sefaria [offers](https://www.sefaria.org/Derashot_HaRan?tab=contents) a digital version, with both Hebrew and English translations.

The English translation is done by [Rabbi Shraga Silverstein](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shraga_Silverstein).