# Seforim and Books online

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books, internet, text

Does anyone know of a website like [this](http://www.ateret4u.com/online/f_01181.html#HtmpReportNum0000_L2) that has the text (not PDF) of *seforim* posted on their website for free?

Comment: I'm assuming you want text-based, and not PDF....if you don't like it, roll back my edit. (based on your preferences [here](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/46149/5323))

Comment: related http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/1382/reference-to-good-texts

Comment: For the record, that website is just the HTML output of torat emet (which was mentioned as a resource by one of the answerers).

Comment: http://www.sourcesonthenet.com

Answer (score 7):

- [Hebrewbooks.org](http://hebrewbooks.org/) has a lot of seforim, though mostly in PDF
  format. (You can get their [*Shas*](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=1&daf=2&format=text) and [Rambam](http://hebrewbooks.org/rambam) as text files.)
- [Torat Emet](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/a_root.html)
- [Sefaria](http://www.sefaria.org/) has a lot of text sefarim, coupled with crowdsourced English
  translations.
- [Wikitext](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A2%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%93_%D7%A8%D7%90%D7%A9%D7%99) (idea taken from [here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1448/5323), *h/t YEZ*)
- [Mechon Mamre](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/), Hebrew and English Tanach, as well as many, many other sefarim. (idea taken from [here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1448/5323), *h/t YEZ*)
- Chabad.org has Tanach [here](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/63255/jewish/The-Bible-with-Rashi.htm) (as well as many other works of chassidus and other topics, under the tab `Learning & Values >> Texts & Writings`)
- http://www.sourcesonthenet.com/ (*h/t msh210 in comments*)
- http://breslev.eip.co.il/ (Breslev seforim *h/t Bachrach44*)
- http://chabadlibrary.org/books/ (Breslev seforim *h/t Bachrach44*)
- http://mobile.tora.ws/ (the back end to the OnYourWay app *h/t Bachrach44*)