# Online דרשות הר"ן in Hebrew block print

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books, internet, rishonim

Does any know where I can find online a pdf of דרשות הר"ן that's in **hebrew text** and not in *Rashi* script/ text?

Comment: Does it have to be PDF or can it be plain text?

Comment: Annoyingly related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/46149/text-of-derashos-haran-online

Answer (score 2):

Take a look [here](http://www.yeshiva.org.il/midrash/?page=10&cat=1648&rc=98) for the text and a concise and clear commentary with PDFs too. (They don't seem to have all the דרשות though.)

Comment: With *nekudos*, too -- great! +1

Answer (score 1):

<strike>Someone started uploading some of them to Sefaria which [you can see here](http://www.sefaria.org/Darashos_HaRan). (Full disclosure: I work for Sefaria). However I'm not actually sure how complete it is. If you let me know where the gaps are, I can (bli neder) assign someone to finish it.</strike>

[Sefaria](http://www.sefaria.org/Darashos_HaRan) has the complete text in both Hebrew and English.

Comment: Do you know if Sefaria is working on a [Ritva](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/48336/5323)?

Comment: @Shokhet It's on the list but it's not being worked on at the moment. Unless I can find someone to seel it to us, it'll probably get added in 6-12 months. (Very rough estimate).

Comment: Ok. If I could be so bold, could I ask for some precedence to be given to Ritva Gittin? I would very much like for my chavrusa to get a copy.....I can type, if that helps. I just don't know where I can find a copy of Ritva that isn't copyrighted.

Comment: @Shokhet Sure. I actually thought I had a deal to buy it a few weeks ago but the quality wasn't good enough so I had to pass. Send me an email at ari_at_sefaria.org and I can share it with you when we get it.