# Text based Ritva / Rabeinu Kresscass?

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books, internet, text, rishonim

[My chavrusa](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/45209/5323) is looking for a text-based copies of Ritva (חידושים מכתב יד) and Rabeinu Kresscass (ריטב"א) on Gittin, so that he could put them into his computer.

**Where can I find a copy of either of the above sefarim, online, as text** (meaning, not pdf)**?**

Comment: Bar ilan [15 characters]

Comment: @Matt True....but I don't currently have access to a copy....I might copy it from a friend's copy, though. ( *while hoping it's legal/halachic* )